# Assync task crashes some times

Tags: android, multithreading, android-listview, android-asynctask

i am developing an application which is gets some data from a web service and display in a list view. i use custom adapter for the list view which is extends by Base Adapter class. and i have use Assync Task for some actions such as for calling the web service and get the responce from it and shows in a Toast (in my list view there is two buttons[Accept and Reject] in each row. when someone clicks Accept it calls a web service ).

so i have implemented my assync tasks inside the Adapter class.

my problem is : sometimes my app crashes when i clicks the list butons.[when running those assync task]. but sometimes it works properly.

the error is something like :

```
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:78)
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:73)
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at com.jsonlist.jsonlist.NewsRowAdapter$ShowResponceForReject.doInBackground(NewsRowAdapter.java:646)
01-08 12:20:26.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21754):    at com.jsonlist.jsonlist.NewsRowAdapter$ShowResponceForReject.doInBackground(NewsRowAdapter.java:1)
```

can anyone tell me where the bug is ?

these are the codes it refers to

```
        public void dialogshow(final String appid){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm your Action!");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes Confirm!!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {



                //  new ShowResponceForAccept().execute("");
                    //dialog.dismiss();
                    Handler mHandler=new Handler();

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() 
                    {
                         public void run()
                         {
                              new ShowResponceForAccept().execute(appid);


                         }
                    });



                /*  ShortList sendandget = new ShortList();
                    //long appoinmentID = Long.valueOf(appid);
                    //long user = Long.valueOf(Uid);
                    String resp = sendandget.getResponceFromServer(appid,"",Uid);
                    Appid = null;
                    Uid = null;
                    //Toast.makeText(mContext, resp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loadListAgain();*/



                }
              })
              .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.show();

    }
```

this is the assync task which is inside the same adapter class

```
    public class ShowResponceForAccept extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();


        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Sending Request", "getting Responce.", true, false);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Looper.myLooper().prepare(); 
        ShortList sendandget = new ShortList();
        String app = arg0[0];
        //long appoinmentID = Long.valueOf(app);
        //long user = Long.valueOf(Uid);
        String resp = sendandget.getResponceFromServer(app,"",Uid);
        loadListAgain();




        //Thread.sleep(10000);
        //String x="Your Request Accepted";

        return resp;
        //return x;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(pDialog != null){
         pDialog.dismiss();
        }

         if(resp.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
             Toast.makeText(mContext, "Your Request has been Successfully Accepted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
         else{
             Toast.makeText(mContext, "Sorry! Try again Later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }


    }


}
```

can some one help me for this ?

Comment: too long a code. need only relevant parts

Comment: Post only lines that have issues

Comment: @Raghunandan   pls C my edited Codes

Comment: @BatuhanC   i have checked it... the error is still exists .. because this error is only occurred only when i press login button when the app first start and when i click the accept or reject in the list view

Comment: @Dunkey  the line is this 
Looper.myLooper().prepare();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with

```
  public class ShowResponceForAccept extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
```

Inside this method your calling

```
  Looper.myLooper().prepare();
```

You should remove UI updation code from doInBackground and push it in postExecute and remove the Looper. That should solve the problem

Comment: can you tell me how assync task runs without doinbackground ?? i do not have much idea about thsese things. but i just know that the return value of doinbakground will be take to the onpostExecute.. im confuce about this.. can you give me some code examples ?

Comment: can you tell me how assync task runs without doinbackground ?? i do not have much idea about thsese things. but i just know that the return value of doinbakground will be take to the onpostExecute.. im confuce about this.. can you give me some code examples ?

Comment: What your doing is right, why are you using that Looper statement? You don't need it. Do whatever callout and processing in doInBackground and return the result. In postExecute update your UI with the result obtained

Comment: i have use that looper statement because when i first try to call assync task it didnt work. so i have seen somewhere to use the looper statement. that is why i use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is there,

You are try to open Dialog In between AsyankTask execute. Do't update UI when AsysnkTask is Running,Update onPostExecute.